# Split string value and use in INSERT and UPDATE command

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Implemented a small ERP system for our kitchen. The system is used to track our groceries, so it contains the goods (referred as food) with its name and UPC code. Over the time the names and upcs started to overlap and creating a data problem. In a first attempt we started to add the manufacturer into the name of the food leafing us with data which looks like this.

| Id | Foodname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Acidophilus;Joghurt |
| 2 | Aibler;Rapsöl |
| 3 | Allos;Choco Confiserie |
| 4 | Alnatura; Dinkel Butterkeks |
| 5 | Alnatura; Salatkerne Mix |

The names are German, sorry for that. The first part of the name is the manufacturer and the second part is the name of the food. I now introduced a new table called 'Manufacturer' which holds an Id and a Name. The table for the foods was extended by the `ManufacturerId` field. I want to have the following tables

#### Manufacturer

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Acidophilus |
| 2 | Aibler |
| 3 | Allos |
| 4 | Alnatura |
| 5 | Alnatura |

#### Food

| Id | Foodname | ManufacturerId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joghurt | 1 |
| 2 | Rapsöl | 2 |
| 3 | Choco Confiserie | 3 |
| 4 | Dinkel Butterkeks | 4 |
| 5 | Salatkerne Mix | 5 |

I tried warping my head around a SQL statement which will solve this for me but I couldn't find any solution.

#### Requiremnts

- Not all entries in the food table already have a manufactuerer assigened. So the query has to filter for item which contain the a ';' in the name. Like

```
   select Name from Foods
   where Foods.Name like '%;%'
   order by [Name]
```

- As seen in the sample data there could be whitespaces after the ';' so the entries for manufactuerer name and food name have to be trimmed.
- A manufacturer has to be created (INSERT) if it isn't already in the table
  `insert into Manufacturer(Name) values (left part of the string split)`
- The name of the food has to be updated to just the name, meaning remove the manufacturer and the ';'
- The ID of the manufactuerer has to be set on the food entry (ManufacturerId)
  `update foods set Name= left part of the string split set ManufacturerId=id of the inserted or found manufacturer`

I tried with the build in functions STRING_SPLIT, LEFT(), RIGHT() but couldn't solve it. According to the [docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) string split also does not garantie that the result is always in the same order. I hope someone has an idea for me.

Thank you

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: This kind of data transformation is definitely doable, but it requires more than one SQL statement

Comment: @RossBush, Database runs on Azure. According to `SELECT @@VERSION` it is Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Apr 19 2021 17:05:18   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very do-able, but metadata changes like this typically require several operational data transforms to complete.

First, here is my understanding of your current state:

```
/*  Current state of things: */
CREATE TABLE Food
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FoodName NVARCHAR(255)
)
GO
INSERT INTO Food (Foodname) VALUES
    (N'Acidophilus;Joghurt'),
    (N'Aibler;Rapsöl'),
    (N'Allos;Choco Confiserie'),
    (N'Alnatura; Dinkel Butterkeks'),
    (N'Alnatura; Salatkerne Mix');
```

Assuming this is correct, then here are the DDL changes:

```
/* New Manufacturer Table */
CREATE TABLE Manufacturer
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(255)
)
GO
/* Extend Food table with new column */
ALTER TABLE Food ADD ManufacturerID INT
GO
```

Once the metadata/DDL has been changed, then you can do the data transforms.  Your case is simple enough that it can be accomplished with two SQL statements:

```
/* Data Transforms */
-- Get the Manufacturer Names:
WITH 
  cteFoodOff AS (SELECT *, CHARINDEX(';', FoodName) AS offset FROM Food)
, cteFoodMan AS 
  (
    SELECT  *, CASE WHEN offset > 0 THEN LEFT(FoodName, offset-1) ELSE '' END AS MName
    FROM    cteFoodOff
    WHERE   offset > 0
  )
INSERT INTO Manufacturer
SELECT  DISTINCT MName
FROM    cteFoodMan
WHERE   MName NOT IN(Select Name From Manufacturer)
;

-- Add ManufacturerIDs into Food table and remove Manufacturer Name from FoodName
WITH 
  cteFoodOff AS (SELECT *, CHARINDEX(';', FoodName) AS offset FROM Food)
, cteFoodMan AS 
  (
    SELECT  *, CASE WHEN offset > 0 THEN LEFT(FoodName, offset-1) ELSE '' END AS MName
    FROM    cteFoodOff
    WHERE   offset > 0
  )
UPDATE cteFoodMan
SET ManufacturerID  = (Select ID From Manufacturer Where Name = MName),
    FoodName = LTRIM(RIGHT(FoodName, LEN(FoodName) - offset))
;
GO
```

If you need to do this while there are any live users/clients (not recommended for metadata changes, because there needs to be code-switching for the client access also), then you may need to wrap this in a transaction, and you may additionally need a View to hide the changes from the older client code.

Comment: Awesome, that is exactly what I was looking for. BIG THX

Answer (score 0):

here is one way :

```
select SUBSTRING(Name,0,CHARINDEX(';',Name))
from Foods
where Foods.Name like '%;%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

The remaining part is to insert data into the appropriate tables.

You can put the SQL below into a CTE for that.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Foodname NVARCHAR(256));
INSERT INTO @tbl (Foodname) VALUES
(N'Acidophilus;Joghurt'),
(N'Aibler;Rapsöl'),
(N'Allos;Choco Confiserie'),
(N'Alnatura; Dinkel Butterkeks'),
(N'Alnatura; Salatkerne Mix');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT *
    , LEFT(Foodname, t.pos-1) AS [Name]
    , TRIM(RIGHT(Foodname, LEN(Foodname) - t.pos)) AS [Food]
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(';',Foodname)) AS t(pos)
WHERE Foodname like '%;%';
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----------------------------+-----+-------------+-------------------+
| ID |          Foodname           | pos |    Name     |       Food        |
+----+-----------------------------+-----+-------------+-------------------+
|  1 | Acidophilus;Joghurt         |  12 | Acidophilus | Joghurt           |
|  2 | Aibler;Rapsöl               |   7 | Aibler      | Rapsöl            |
|  3 | Allos;Choco Confiserie      |   6 | Allos       | Choco Confiserie  |
|  4 | Alnatura; Dinkel Butterkeks |   9 | Alnatura    | Dinkel Butterkeks |
|  5 | Alnatura; Salatkerne Mix    |   9 | Alnatura    | Salatkerne Mix    |
+----+-----------------------------+-----+-------------+-------------------+
```